# How can i redirect /?lang=en|ru to /?lang=en#googtrans(en|ru)?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string

How can I add the Google translate parameter #googtrans(en|de) or other language, so the translation happens automatically?

Basically, when the user goes to https://example.com/page/?lang=de they are redirected to [https://example.com/page/?lang=en#googtrans(en|de)](https://example.com/page/?lang=en#googtrans(en%7Cde))

I use this .htaccess rule, but it's not working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^/?lang=en#googtrans(en|[a-z]{2}) [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unless ‘en’ is treated specially the description here is not viable since a request like `^/?lang=en#googtrans(en|xx)` will also match the redirect rule and redirect again. Please clarify by editing the question the actual intent

Comment: Also the fragment (#blah) is never received by Apache, any rule that includes it will never match anything

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding edited Rules here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page/?\?lang=([a-z]{2})\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/?lang=%1#googtrans(%1) [R=301,L,NE]
```

---

---

With your shown samples(this is considering that you are hitting URL like: https://example.com/page/?lang=de in browser), please try following .htaccess Rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page/?lang=%1#googtrans(%1) [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried this, but it didn't work... It stays on https://example.com/page/?lang=de.

Comment: @Dalv, oh ok, I thought you don't want to redirect. Please try my edited rules now and let me know how it goes cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I think we are getting there. There are two issues: 1. The redirect happens in the root domain - I need only the https://example.com/page/?lang=de to redirect to https://example.com/page/?lang=en#googtrans(de) 2. The second issue is the '#' character is being displayed as %23 in the URL.

Comment: @Dalv, sure, I have fixed both the issues now. Please do check it once and let me know how it goes, make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @Dalv, Could you please do try my EDIT rules and let me know.

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/?lang=en#googtrans(%1) [R=301,L,NE] - works on root domain. However, the RewriteRule ^page/?$ doesn't do the redirect.

Comment: @Dalv. Kindly use Edit rules which uses THE_REQUEST variable one once

Comment: Thanks - I tried the RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page/?\?lang=([a-z]{2})\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ page/?lang=%1#googtrans(%1) [R=301,L,NE] - the redirect is not working...

Comment: @Dalv, ok I am assuming you are hitting link https://example.com/page/?lang=de here. Also could you please do let me know how your page is getting served? Is it index.php in backend? Do you have other rules too apart from these ones?

Comment: Yes, I'm hitting example.com/page/?lang=de . It's a WordPress website, RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: @Dalv, I believe what AD7six is saying in comments is right, you need to remove `#` from query string, try putting `&` in case use it in your query string?

Comment: #googtrans is what Google translate uses to make the translation... When I put & the translation doesn't happen.

Comment: @Dalv please recognise that even if you get this redirect to work it's going to do this: `/?lang=xx` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|xx)` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|xx)` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|xx)` .... You need to think about that, and edit the question to make sense before it can be answered.

Comment: Small correction - It's going to do _this_: `/?lang=xx` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|xx)` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|en)`-> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|en)` -> 301 -> `/?lang=en#googtrans(en|en)` ....